# MediaPlayer переключение на следующий трек

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать по нажатию кнопки Play что бы композиции из массива проигрывались одна за другой:
(сейчас,если песня заканчивается,то плеер останавливается)

```
          private Button buttonPlayStop;
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private SeekBar seekBar;
        int index=0;
        public int[] soundsRawResIds = new int[]{R.raw.belarus, R.raw.russian, R.raw.japan,
                R.raw.litva, R.raw.england, R.raw.finlandia, R.raw.france};

        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initViews();

        }
            private void initViews() {
        for(int i=0;i<soundsRawResIds.length;i++) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundsRawResIds[i]);

        }
            buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundsRawResIds[index]);

            seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    seekChange(v);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        private void seekChange(View v){
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
            }
        }
        public void playAndStop(View v){
            if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
                buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
                try{
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
            }else {
                buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
        public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
            }else{
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }
    }

Разметка:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:progress="0"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"/>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/play_str"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="playAndStop"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonPlayStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"/>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/timeSound"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:text="00:00"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,не тот код,поправил